# Invalid project path: Include path not found (/usr/src/gtest/include)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i followed the basic tutorial but come out with the warning "Include path not found" in all four package, talker, listener, deployment, behaviour. Lastly, "roslaunch deployment system.launch" can not be run. pls help me. thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206000/invalid-project-path:-include-path-not-found-(/usr/src/gtest/include)/) by [soon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21990/soon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Project -> Preferences -> C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols
Delete `/usr/src/gtest/include` (near the bottom of the list).

You might need to build `gtest` as well:

```
# See below for source url
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
# sudo apt-get install cmake #  <==  Not required since ROS already provides this
cd /usr/src/gtest
sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt
sudo make
# copy or symlink libgtest.a and libgtest_main.a to your /usr/lib folder
sudo cp *.a /usr/lib  # <= Probably not required either due to existing include paths
```

Refer to: http://www.landabin.com/2014/09/27/getting-started-google-test-gtest-ubuntu/

---

Originally posted by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) with karma: 302 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3